# XSLT Template not being applied

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML with internal XSLT. Some of the templates are being applied and some of them aren't, and I can't figure out a rhyme or reason.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dmodule [
  <!ELEMENT xsl:stylesheet (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
    id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<dmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:nsiv="http://www.pbmassoc.com/nsiv" nsiv:spec-issue="3.0.1">
<?MENTORPATH?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" id="style1">
        <xsl:template match="/">        
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>XML Compare</title>
                    <style>
                        table, th, td {
                            border: 1px solid black;
                        }
                        .warning {
                            color: red;
                            font-size: 16pt;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            }
                        .caution {
                            font-size: 14pt;
                            font-weight:bold;}
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>              
                    <h1>                    
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/modelic"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/sdc"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/chapnum"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/section"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/subsect"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/subject"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/discode"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/discodev"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/incode"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/incodev"/>-
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmc/avee/itemloc"/>: 
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmtitle/techname"/> -  
                        <xsl:value-of select="dmodule/idstatus/dmaddres/dmtitle/infoname"/>
                    </h1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </body>
            </html> 
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/refs">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <caption>References</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data Module Code</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/refs/refdm"/>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/refs/refdm">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="avee/modelic"/>-<xsl:value-of select="avee/sdc"/>-<xsl:value-of select="avee/chapnum"/>-
                    <xsl:value-of select="avee/section"/><xsl:value-of select="avee/subsect"/>
                    -<xsl:value-of select="avee/subject"/>-<xsl:value-of select="avee/discode"/><xsl:value-of select="avee/discodev"/>-
                    <xsl:value-of select="avee/incode"/><xsl:value-of select="avee/incodev"/>
                    -<xsl:value-of select="avee/itemloc"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="dmtitle/techname"/> - <xsl:value-of select="dmtitle/infoname"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/reqconds">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <caption>Pre-Requisites</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data Module Code</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/reqconds/reqcondm"/>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/reqconds/reqcondm">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/modelic"/>-<xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/sdc"/>-
                    <xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/chapnum"/>-<xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/section"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/subsect"/>-<xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/subject"/>
                    -<xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/discode"/><xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/discodev"/>-
                    <xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/incode"/><xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/incodev"/>
                    -<xsl:value-of select="refdm/avee/itemloc"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "reqcond"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <caption>Support Equipment</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nomenclature</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer Code</th>
                    <th>Part Number</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip/supeqli/supequi"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip/nosupeq"/>
                <xsl:if test = "not(dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip)">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "3">No Support Equipment</td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>   
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip/supeqli/supequi">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "nomen"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "identno/mfc"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "identno/pnr"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip/nosupeq">
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "3">No Support Equipment</td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <caption>Consumables</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nomenclature</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer Code</th>
                    <th>Part Number</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies/supplyli/supply"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies/nosupply"/>
                <xsl:if test = "not(dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies)">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "3">No Consumables</td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "xsl:stylesheet"/>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies/supplyli/supply">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "nomen"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "identno/mfc"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "identno/pnr"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies/nosupply">
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "3">No Consumables</td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/spares">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <caption>Spares</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nomenclature</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer Code</th>
                    <th>Part Number</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/spares/sparesli/spare"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/spares/nospares"/>
                <xsl:if test = "not(dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supplies)">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "3">No Spares</td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
                <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/spares/sparesli/spare">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "nomen"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "identno/mfc"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select = "identno/pnr"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/safety">
                    <br/>
                    <h2>Safety</h2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select = "warning"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select = "caution"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select = "note"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "warning">
            <p class = "warning">WARNING</p>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "para">
            <p><xsl:value-of select = "."/></p>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "caution">
            <p clas = "caution">Caution</p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "note">
            <p class = "note">Note</p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/mainfunc">
            <h2>Procedure</h2>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ol>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/mainfunc/step1">
            <li><xsl:value-of select = "para"/></li>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "idstatus"/>
        <xsl:template match = "closereqs">
            <br/>
            <table>
                <caption>Close-Up Requirements</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data Module</th>
                    <th>Requirement</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "reqconds"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test = "not(dmodule/content/proced/closereqs)">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan = "2">No Close-Up Requirements</td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select = "noconds"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match = "noconds">
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2">No Close-Up Requirements</td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:output method="html"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>


    <idstatus>
        <dmaddres>
            <dmc>
                <avee>
                    <modelic>XYZ</modelic>
                    <sdc>AA</sdc>
                    <chapnum>01</chapnum>
                    <section>3</section>
                    <subsect>4</subsect>
                    <subject>11</subject>
                    <discode>02</discode>
                    <discodev>A</discodev>
                    <incode>520</incode>
                    <incodev>A</incodev>
                    <itemloc>A</itemloc>
                </avee>
            </dmc>
            <dmtitle>
                <techname>XYZ Device</techname>
                <infoname>Removal</infoname>
            </dmtitle>
            <issno inwork="11" issno="000" type="new"/>
            <issdate day="05" month="22" year="2009"/>
            <language country="US" language="en"/>
        </dmaddres>
        <status>
            <rpc rpcname="Acme">1234</rpc>
            <orig>1234</orig>
            <applic>
                <displaytext>ALL</displaytext>
            </applic>
            <brexref>
                <refdm>
                    <avee>
                        <modelic>XYZ</modelic>
                        <sdc>AA</sdc>
                        <chapnum>05</chapnum>
                        <section>0</section>
                        <subsect>2</subsect>
                        <subject>20</subject>
                        <discode>35</discode>
                        <discodev>A</discodev>
                        <incode>015</incode>
                        <incodev>A</incodev>
                        <itemloc>C</itemloc>
                    </avee>
                </refdm>
            </brexref>
            <qa>
                <firstver type="tabtop"/>
                <secver type="tabtop"/>
            </qa>
            <remarks>
                <p>Ref Designator: </p>
            </remarks>
        </status>
    </idstatus>
    <content>
        <refs>
            <refdm>
                <avee>
                    <modelic>XYZ</modelic>
                    <sdc>AA</sdc>
                    <chapnum>01</chapnum>
                    <section>1</section>
                    <subsect>1</subsect>
                    <subject>10</subject>
                    <discode>10</discode>
                    <discodev>A</discodev>
                    <incode>100</incode>
                    <incodev>A</incodev>
                    <itemloc>C</itemloc>
                </avee>
                <dmtitle>
                    <techname>Pre-Maintenance Checklist</techname>
                    <infoname>Pre-Operation</infoname>
                </dmtitle>
            </refdm>
            <reftp>
                <pubcode>XYZ-7</pubcode>
                <pubtitle>Installation and Repair Practices </pubtitle>
            </reftp>
        </refs>
        <proced>
            <prelreqs>
                <reqconds>
                    <reqcondm>
                        <reqcond>Pre-Maintenance Checklist</reqcond>
                        <refdm>
                            <avee>
                                <modelic>XYZ</modelic>
                                <sdc>AA</sdc>
                                <chapnum>01</chapnum>
                                <section>1</section>
                                <subsect>1</subsect>
                                <subject>10</subject>
                                <discode>10</discode>
                                <discodev>A</discodev>
                                <incode>100</incode>
                                <incodev>A</incodev>
                                <itemloc>C</itemloc>
                            </avee>
                            <dmtitle>
                                <techname>Pre-Maintenance Checklist</techname>
                                <infoname>Pre-Operation</infoname>
                            </dmtitle>
                        </refdm>
                    </reqcondm>
                </reqconds>
                <reqpers>
                    <person man="2"/>
                </reqpers>
                <supequip>
                    <supeqli>
                        <supequi>
                            <nomen>Lift</nomen>
                            <identno>
                                <mfc>123</mfc>
                                <pnr id="d6791e219" nsiv:sfield="pnr pnrsupeq">301–781</pnr>
                        </identno>
                        <qty>1</qty>
                        </supequi>
                        <supequi>
                            <nomen>Screwdriver</nomen>
                            <identno>
                                <mfc>113</mfc>
                                <pnr id="d6791e229" nsiv:sfield="pnr pnrsupeq">01534343</pnr>
                            </identno>
                            <qty>1</qty>
                        </supequi>
                    </supeqli>
                </supequip>
                <supplies>
                    <nosupply/>
                </supplies>
                <spares>
                    <nospares/>
                </spares>
                <safety>
                    <safecond>
                        <warning><para>Heavy lift involved.</para></warning>
                    </safecond>
                </safety>
            </prelreqs>
            <mainfunc>
                <step1>
                    <para>Disconnect the thing from the other thing.</para>
                </step1>
                <step1>
                    <para>Remove nut (u), lock washer (v), and four flat washers (w).</para>
                </step1>
                <step1>
                    <para>Loosen  fasteners (x).</para>
                </step1>
                <step1>
                    <warning>
                        <para>Two people shall support component when handling component. Failure to comply 
                        could result in personnel injury and damage to equipment.</para>
                    </warning>
                    <para>Lift and remove the heavy thing.</para>
                </step1>
            </mainfunc>
            <closereqs>
                <reqconds>
                    <noconds/>
                </reqconds>
            </closereqs>
        </proced>
    </content>
</dmodule>
```

The output I get in Chrome looks like this:

> **XYZ- AA- 01- 34- 11- 02A- 520A- A: XYZ Device - Removal**
>
> References 
>   Data Module Code  Title
>
> Pre-Requisites 
>   Data Module Code  Title
>
> Support Equipment 
>   Nomenclature  Manufacturer Code   Part Number 
>   No Support Equipment
>
> Consumables 
>   Nomenclature  Manufacturer Code   Part Number 
>   No Consumables
>
> Spares Nomenclature   Manufacturer Code   Part Number 
>   No Spares
>
> Safety 
>   Procedure
>   1.    Disconnect the thing from the other thing.
>   2.    Remove nut (u), lock washer (v), and four flat washers (w).
>   3.    Loosen fasteners (x).
>   4.    Lift and remove the heavy thing.
>
> Close-Up Requirements 
>   Data Module   Requirement 
>   No Close-Up Requirements

The items that aren’t appearing the way I expect them to are the support equipment ("supequi" element), the warnings ("warning" element), the references ("refdm" element) and the required conditions ("reqcondm" element).

Comment: Are you sure the stylesheet with a line like `<xsl:applytemplates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip/nosupeq"/>` compiles at all?

Comment: It did, but I fixed the error anyway.  Maybe Chrome just ignored it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in places like `<xsl:template match = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip">` you then don't want to use `<xsl:apply-templates select = "dmodule/content/proced/prelreqs/supequip/supeqli/supequi"/>` but rather a path relative to the matched element, like `<xsl:apply-templates select = "supeqli/supequi"/>`.